# Как позволить пользователю менять картинки слайдера?

Tags: wordpress

Перевожу сайт в ВП (верстаю шаблон).

В общем, есть такой кусок html:

```html
<div class="flexslider"><!-- .slider-->
<ul class="slides">
<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
<li>
   <img  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Это слайдер, с которым работает скрипт, в дальнейшем. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь, ничего не шарящий в ВП, мог через админку отредактировать страницу (в визуальном режиме). Удалил из слайдера ненужное барахло, добавил свои новые фото, изменил порядок фоток и т.д. Так понимаю, что нужен какой-либо плагин с галереей. Или как это можно сделать? Кто подскажет? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Один из самых популярных плагинов - Meta Slider. 
Создание слайдеров выведено на отдельную страницу, а в контент страницы они вставляются с помощью шорткода `[metaslider id=id_слайдера]`.
Полный видео-туториал на странице самого слайдера - https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно, чтобы слайдер работал именно с теми стилями и по тому скрипту, что мне дали. Нужно только как-то предусмотреть работу пользователя непосредственно с картинками.

Comment: Метаслайдер создает приблизительно такой же маркап, оборачивая его в `div` с `id=id_слайдера`, внутри лежит `ul` с классом `slides`, а дальше `li` с `img` внутри.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить выше сказанный плагин, разместите пробный слайдер на любую страницу, в коде гляньте какие у него классы. Потом найдите в папках этого плагина файлик, в котором размещается эти классы и замените их на свои. Если не знаете как это сделать, распишу подробно...

```css
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
    display: block;
}
.flexslider .slides {
    zoom: 1;
}
.slides, .slides > li, .flex-control-nav, .flex-direction-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}


.flex-control-nav {
    /* width: 100%; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 96%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.slides, .slides > li, .flex-control-nav, .flex-direction-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;}

.flex-control-nav li {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    display: block;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
    background: #dbc4cc;
    background: rgba(219, 196, 204, 0.90);
    cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
a {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
```

```html
<ul class="slides">...</ul> - это просто слайдер
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
<li><a class="flex-active">1</a></li>
<li><a class="">2</a></li>
<li><a class="">3</a></li>
</ol>
```

```html
 <ul class="slides">...</ul> - это просто слайдер
    <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
    <li><a class="flex-active">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
      </a></li>
    <li><a class="">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
      </a></li>
    <li><a class="">
      <img  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
      </a></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Во многом разобрался, но не могу повторить дизайн переключателей. В чем суть (см. скриншоты):
А классы переключателей почему-то глянуть не могу через просмотр кода страницы

Скриншоты:
https://www.imageshost.eu/image/ogK
https://www.imageshost.eu/image/ogb

Comment: А можно ссылку на сайт? Если навигация есть, то её маркап можно посмотреть в инспекторе.

Comment: Без ссылки на сайт (донор) не поможем )

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов http://arinadavidova.com/ краду отсюда (переверстываю шаблон).
п.с. может, тут тоже сможете подсказать (пагинация, слайдер) - мои беды пока что в ВП
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467231/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-wordpress

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ свой. Смотрите выше. Может разберётесь. По поводу пагинации не в курсе я

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов спасибо большое за стили, только вот клики по навам не рабочие.. Не подскажете, как исправить?

Comment: а дай пожалуйста ссылку на сайт свой. или можешь на email прислать мне. А то я замученный сейчас, мне так проще будет

Comment: Посмотри я еще один html код добавил к ответу. Попробуй его вставить. Вместо предыдущего.