# Пагинация в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Здравствуйте. Переношу сайт с html/css/js на ВП.

В общем, суть: есть страница (не index.php), где выводятся записи одной определенной рубрики (их может быть много). Поэтому нужна пагинация.

Сама пагинация отверстана вот так (фрагмент кода):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="prev">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="next">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Полный код:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div id="portfolio-gallery" class="page gallery round-gallery">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="page-head">
          <h2><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'description', true );?></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts( 'cat=10'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 item">
        <!-- .row1-->
        <a class="gallery-box" href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '', true );?>">
          <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(null,null,full);?>
          <div class="gallery-overlay">
            <div class="overlay-data">
              <span><?php the_title();?></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="prev">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a>
          </li>
          <li class="next">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="push"></div>
</div>
<?php /*место кода для пагинации пробовал использовать post_pagination() - работает некорректно, т.к. скорее всего из-за того, что страница не явл индекс.пхп */ ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Выводится записи одной определенной рубрики (их может быть много). Поэтому нужна пагинация. Не могу ее применить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень нужно.
Сделать страницу через общие настройки вп, что она является страницей записей не могу, т.к. подобная схема (вывод одной определенной рубрики + пагинация) будет ещё на нескольких страницах. Помогите, пожалуйста, очень нужно! Буду Вам бескрайне благодарен.

---

@Umer не получается все равно( Теперь делаю немного по-другому, но все равно не выходит. Смотрите, у меня структура такая:
страница записей - страница for_pagination
статическая главная - страница "главная" (main)
Как я понял страница записей отрабатывает через index.php. Поэтому в этом файле прописал пагинацию (через posts_pagination($args) и все работает!

Теперь мне нужно сделать пагинацию по ссылке */category/portfolio
для этого у меня есть свой шаблон для этой категории category-portfolio.php, где запрашиваю записи именно этой категории, циклом вывожу. Именно здесь у меня не получается применить пагинацию (она отображается, но по клику на вторую страницу, линк меняется, а содержимое страницы нет, т.е. другие записи не появляются - по умолчанию тут пагинация сама не появляется, добавляю опять же через posts_pagination($args), параметры те же, что и в index.php). После добавления пхп кода пагинация тут появляется, но не работает сама суть (описал выше)
Уже так намучался с этим  Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Почитайте про функцию WordPress paginate_links(), она должна вам помочь http://wp-kama.ru/function/paginate_links

Comment: @Umer см отредактированный вопрос